# How to vertically center a text inside a link

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="zocial paypal"><span>Update Profile</span></a>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nkvpqpy1/

How can I center the "Update Profile" text vertically centered in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `line-height: 2.5em`:

```
    .zocial span
    {
        padding: .5em 0 0 0;
        line-height: 2.5em;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nkvpqpy1/1/

Comment: How can I do without a `span`?

Answer (score 2):

the `line-height` is the best answer, but you may do this too:

```
padding: .2em .95em 0 0;
```

Just adding a slight top padding

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/b1ra5006/)

Answer (score 1):

```
a span {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top padding from the `span` and make it `vertical-align:middle`

So, change your existing rule to

```
.zocial span
{
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/nkvpqpy1/5/